# How can I fix my OpenGL build environment on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, g++

**UPDATE**

I've sorted this by explicitly adding the appropriate -I and -L options, but I'm curious as to why this is necessary now when it wasn't before?  On the plus side those annoying library out-of-sync warnings are gone.

**UPDATE ENDS**

I've broken my OSX OpenGL build environment.  I'm building from terminal (using make) with g++, for example:

> g++ -o myprog main.o -lglfw -lglew -framework OpenGL

and getting errors:

> ld: library not found for -lglfw clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

These are in addition to compiler errors such as:

> g++ -c main.cpp main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'GL/glew.h' file not found

So it seems the OpenGL libraries and includes have been lost.  Everything was working fine until  I executed the command:

> export SDKROOT="$(xcode-select -p)/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk"

Which I did to try and fix warning messages like:

> ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//OpenGL.framework/OpenGL.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//OpenGL.framework/OpenGL are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.

I got that 'fix' from here: [macOS framework lib problem](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/issues/1181#issuecomment-523940683)

I realise it was reckless running commands that I don't fully understand but nonetheless... now I can't compile/link any OpenGL code and after scouring the internet for help I've come up with nothing, so here I am.

I'm running OSX 10.13.6 on a 2013 MacBook Pro.

First post BTW so please forgive me if I've not provided enough detail.

Comment: `xcode-select -p` prints the path to Xcode. `export SDKROOT="$(xcode-select -p)/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk"` sets the variable `SDKROOT` for the current terminal session only. Reboot your system and everything should be as before.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this has restored everything, and for now I've disabled all warnings with -w until I can sort out this library file syncing business